# K800 USB Wireless Keyboard - keyboard repeat rate intermittent problems

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard, autorepeat

Any advice as to how to debug this:

My K800 USB Wireless Keyboard's repeat rate intermittently stops working. 
It will start behaving erratically and when holding a key down it will either not repeat at all, or only repeat 3-4 times.

This occurs from any X11 (using xmonad), including konsole or gnome-terminal, etc. If i switch to a pseudo/virtual terminal ( C-Alt-F2 etc. ) , then the repeat rate is fine.

I have tried `xset r rate 350 30`  and it doesn't work.

I have left it overnight and come back the next day to find that, magically, it all of a sudden works correctly.

Then randomly, at some point in the future, it will start again.  And randomly it will stop later on.

I don't even know how to start to investigate this problem.  I suspected maybe it is udev related?  I tried something like this, as a gamble:

```
sudo rm -rf /dev/usb/*
sudo rm -rf /dev/bus/usb/*
sudo udevadm trigger
```

and it didn't help.

Also  - when selecting text with the mouse in konsole ( but not firefox ),
the same stutter/stop occurs when the problem is happening. I can select maybe 1 or 2 lines and then it stops selecting ( despite still having the mouse button pressed down )

uname: Linux 3.5.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 7 19:30:49 CEST 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Perhaps low battery? BTW, if you find out, please answer your own question for future reference.